# SSAS KPI in a perspective

Tags: ssas, perspective, msbi, kpi

I have a user group that wants a KPI off a measure include in their reports.  There are other user groups who do not wish to have this measure included.  I was thinking of creating perspectives that filters that measure from their views.

When I try to create the perspective, I do not see the KPI as an option to check.  I see the column name as well as the measure as an option to filter, but not the KPI.  Hence, when I go to analyze the data in excel, all of my KPIs appear as an option to include, while the measure does not.

Does anyone know how I can include a KPI in a perspective through SSAS?  If this is not possible, is anyone aware of a different way to filter a KPI?

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of objects that can be included in an SSAS perspective. KPIs will be in a separate section from measure groups. [MSSQLTips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3213/sql-server-analysis-services-perspectives/) has a good article about SSAS perspectives. You can see from the image in that article that KPIs are grouped together.  You can expand the KPIs section and choose the ones you want to include.

[image: SSAS Perspective]

If you are using perspectives, I also recommend using [BIDS Helper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/). It has a feature called [Tri-State Perspectives](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tri-State%20Perspectives&referringTitle=Documentation) that highlights measure groups or dimensions that contain children that are not part of the perspective. This is helpful because new items (measures, dimension attributes, KPIs, calculations, etc.) are not included in perspectives by default.